# error in casting rootobject() in qt main.cpp for communicating with qml

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick

I am new to qt quick ,i tried to write a code to call c++ slot on qml signal

```
//main.cpp 
#include "qtquick1applicationviewer.h"
#include "QApplication"
#include"authenticate.h"

     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
      QApplication app(argc, argv);
      QDeclarativeView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
      QObject *item = view.rootObject();

      Authenticate myClass;
      QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

     view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

error is:
main.cpp:15: error: cannot convert 'QGraphicsObject*' to 'QObject*' in initialization
         QObject *item = viewer.rootObject();

```
     //main.qml
     import QtQuick 1.0 

    Item {
    id: item
    width: 100; height: 100

    signal qmlSignal(String msg)

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: item.qmlSignal("Hello from QML")
    }
}


                                       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly cast to `QObject *` :

```
QObject *item = qobject_cast< QObject * >( view.rootObject() );
```

Also make sure you have included `QGraphicsObject` :

```
#include <QGraphicsObject>
```